Getting Google play store deployment permission warning
While deployment Flutter app, am getting below warning on play console:
Your use of exact alarms is causing your app to crash for some Android users
Your app schedules exact alarms without checking whether the SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission has been granted. This is causing your app to crash for users on Android 14 because the permission is no longer granted by default.
In most cases, alternative methods of scheduling work or inexact alarms are more appropriate. If your use of exact alarms is justified, update your app so that it checks this permission is granted before scheduling.
Authentication via WebView
Your app performs authentication via WebViews, which leads to security and usability issues. Please see this Google Help Center article for details.
com.parkstreet.parkstreet.LoginViaAppleActivity.setupAppleWebviewDialog
Manifest:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />


In your code. You need to ask for alarm permission from user. you can do this when starting the app or when scheduling an alarm. If the permission is not granted by user then you can't schedule any alarm. When user grant permission then you can schedule alarms and it'll work fine. For more info. https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/alarms/schedule#exact-user-grant


SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM, the permission introduced in Android 12 for apps
to schedule exact alarms, is no longer being pre-granted to most newly
installed apps targeting Android 13 and higher (will be set to denied
by default)

Starting Android 13, you need to request SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission as it's no longer granted by default. Schedule the alarm only if permission is granted. You can check the sdk version before scheduling the alarm. If Android 12 or below, schedule it as usual, if 13 & above, check permission and schedule alarm only if permission is available
schedule-exact-alarms
